# Should I be using a design pattern when creating these objects?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a lot of duplicate code in my program that basically follows this structure:

```
If condition is true
    Create ErrorRecord object
    Call ThrowTerminatingError(error object)
End if
```

The structure of this code is exactly the same for each instance, one of two parameters are different. So for example this is part of one of my methods

```
protected void ProcessRecord()
{
    ...

    var login = PrivateFunctions.GetLogin(samAccountName);

    if (login == null)
    {
        var errorRecord = new ErrorRecord(
            new NullReferenceException($"A login for the user account '{samAccountName}' does not exist in the database."),
            "LoginNotFound",
            ErrorCategory.ObjectNotFound,
            login);

        ThrowTerminatingError(errorRecord);
    }

    var user = PrivateFunctions.GetUser(login);

    if (user == null)
    {
        var errorRecord = new ErrorRecord(
            new NullReferenceException($"A user for the login '{login.Name}' does not exist in the database."),
            "UserNotFound",
            ErrorCategory.ObjectNotFound,
            user);

        ThrowTerminatingError(errorRecord);
    }
   ...
}
```

I'm thinking I could create a static method with parameters to create the ErrorObject and initialise it as required. For example:

```
static internal ErrorObject CreateUserError(Login login)
{
    return new ErrorRecord(
        new NullReferenceException($"A user for the login '{login.Name}' does not exist in the database."),
        "UserNotFound",
        ErrorCategory.ObjectNotFound,
        user);
}
```

And then used:

```
ThrowTerminatingErrorRecord(StaticClass.CreateUserError(login));
```

Is there a design pattern I could use or is there a better approach?

Edit:
In response to the first comment, this is what happens if I throw an exception rather than constructing the error record:

Calling ThrowTerminatingError:

```
Get-DatabaseUserInformation : "A login for the user account 'domain\username' does not exist in the database."
+ Get-DatabaseUserInformation <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-DatabaseUserInformation], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : "LoginNotFound",Module.Cmdlet
```

Throwing an exception:

```
Get-DatabaseUserInformation : An exception was thrown.
+ get-databaseuser <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-DatabaseUserInformation], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Module.Cmdlet
```

Comment: if you can write code which generates the logging info from less information. you don't need the extra information. I would just do Throw New Exception("user not found : " + login); if anything, surely user not found is not an exception?

Comment: This is a PowerShell Cmdlet, so I can't just throw exceptions. If I just throw an exception, PowerShell reports a generic exception which doesn't explain what went wrong.